# React Router v6 not working with URL Slugs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make react-router-dom work with a simple url: /user/{name} but for some reason cannot get it to load the page with the url slug for the name.

This is the return of my App function component:

```
    <>
      <MainNavBar navigation={navigation} />
      <Routes>
        <Route index={true} element={<Home />} exact />
        <Route path="user" element={<User />} exact>
          <Route
            path=":name"
            render={
              ({ match: { params: { name } } }) => {
                console.log(name);
                console.log("test2");
                return (<UserPage
                  userName={name}
                />);
              }}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
```

This is the User component; a placeholder for my debugging atm.

```
const User = () => (
  <div>
    <header className="App-header">
      <Outlet />
    </header>
  </div>
);
```

When I go to http://localhost:3000/user/test it loads the `User` component but not the children (the Outlet/UserPage elements)

I've tried lots of combinations but seem to be doing something wrong, so any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` components no longer have `render` or `component` props, they render their components on the `element` prop. Use the `useParams` hook to access the route match params. If `UserPage` is a component that *can't* use React hooks, then use a wrapper function component to access the route match param and pass it as a prop.

```
const UserPageWrapper = () => {
  const { name } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ name }); // <-- log param in effect
  }, [name]);
  return <UserPage userName={name} />;
};
```

...

```
<>
  <MainNavBar navigation={navigation} />
  <Routes>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="user" element={<User />}>
      <Route path=":name" element={<UserPageWrapper />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</>
```